# Obscure links in Header

Tags: php, html, css

Currently have a site built using SASS, however due to the fact it was not compiling we decided to edit the cw-styles CSS in our DEV environment and upload this to the FTP instead.

This is how we are linking the css in the Head section currently:

```
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">        
<link href="/<?php echo SITE_FOLDER; ?>/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />                   
<link href="/common/js/image/swipe.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<link href="/mse/css/cw-styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

However on uploading this, in the Head section the link to the stylesheet on the Live site has broken, giving us a link that looks like this:

```
<link href="/mse,_uploads,_all.crush.css,q23409834296+common,_js,_image,_swipe.css+mse,_css,_cw-styles.css+common,_js,_lightbox,_lightbox.css+common,_js,_image,_swipe.css.pagespeed.cc.0Keg4MRi-i.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Anyone experienced this, or clues as to why this is happening?

Comment: I think this is not a CSS question...

Comment: This is some kind of aggregation functionality, that combines multiple external CSS resources into a single one, to save on HTTP requests. I think someone over there should go read the manual for the system you are using, because you seem to have little clue as to how it actually works ...

Comment: CBroe - Very useful thanks! I get that it compiles it into the final CW-Styles, but dont understand why the link has broken as we have done this (compiled and uploaded the stylesheet css file) with other sites?

Comment: Evil Page.class.php file causing it ;)